# Custom JavaScript Contact form 7

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I am getting a syntax error for the below. The javascript is supposed to check the brand and then display its sub-products. Currently, the form is not displaying the sub-products [var brands]

I tried to check the format of the array but everything seems correct. I believe the code is correct but perhaps the format of the array is not. [var brands]

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
                <th>Quantity (cl)</th>
                <th>IBA Associate Member</th>
    <th>Recipe Ingredients (Product)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
                 <td>[text text-547]</td>
           <td>[select* brand-01 id:product1 "please select IBA associate member" "JIM BEAM FAMILY" "COGNAC" "PREMIUM BOURBON" "LIQUEUR" "JAPANESE WHISKY" "SCOTCH WHISKY"  "GIN" "DE KUYPER ESSENTIALS"  "DE KUYPER VARIATIONS"  "DE KUYPER SOURS""DE KUYPER ORIGINAL ELIXIRS"  "SPECIALITIES"  "RUTTE" "PREMIUMS" "CREAMS & ADVOCAAT" "PUCKERS & SCHNAPPS" "FABBRI SYRUPS" "ZERO RANGE"  "SPECIALS" "PULPS" "GOURMET SAUCE" "GOLD RANGE" "PITTED CHERRIES IN LIQUEUR" "CHERRIES IN LIQUE UR"  "SOUR LINE" "AMARENA FABBRI" "MOLECULAR" "MONIN PREMIUM SYRUPS" "MONIN CONCENTRATE" "MONIN FRUIT PURÉES/FRUIT MIX" "MONIN SAUCES" "MONIN LIQUEURS"]</td>
    <td>[text* product1]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
         <td>[text text-548]</td>
           <td>[select* brand-02 id:product2 "please select IBA associate member" "JIM BEAM FAMILY" "COGNAC" "PREMIUM BOURBON" "LIQUEUR" "JAPANESE WHISKY" "SCOTCH WHISKY"  "GIN" "DE KUYPER ESSENTIALS"  "DE KUYPER VARIATIONS"  "DE KUYPER SOURS""DE KUYPER ORIGINAL ELIXIRS"  "SPECIALITIES"  "RUTTE" "PREMIUMS" "CREAMS & ADVOCAAT" "PUCKERS & SCHNAPPS" "FABBRI SYRUPS" "ZERO RANGE"  "SPECIALS" "PULPS" "GOURMET SAUCE" "GOLD RANGE" "PITTED CHERRIES IN LIQUEUR" "CHERRIES IN LIQUE UR"  "SOUR LINE" "AMARENA FABBRI" "MOLECULAR" "MONIN PREMIUM SYRUPS" "MONIN CONCENTRATE" "MONIN FRUIT PURÉES/FRUIT MIX" "MONIN SAUCES" "MONIN LIQUEURS"]</td>
    <td>[text* product2]</td>
  </tr>
       <tr>
    <td>3</td>
         <td>[text text-549]</td>
           <td>[select* brand-03 id:product3 "please select IBA associate member" "JIM BEAM FAMILY" "COGNAC" "PREMIUM BOURBON" "LIQUEUR" "JAPANESE WHISKY" "SCOTCH WHISKY"  "GIN" "DE KUYPER ESSENTIALS"  "DE KUYPER VARIATIONS"  "DE KUYPER SOURS""DE KUYPER ORIGINAL ELIXIRS"  "SPECIALITIES"  "RUTTE" "PREMIUMS" "CREAMS & ADVOCAAT" "PUCKERS & SCHNAPPS" "FABBRI SYRUPS" "ZERO RANGE"  "SPECIALS" "PULPS" "GOURMET SAUCE" "GOLD RANGE" "PITTED CHERRIES IN LIQUEUR" "CHERRIES IN LIQUE UR"  "SOUR LINE" "AMARENA FABBRI" "MOLECULAR" "MONIN PREMIUM SYRUPS" "MONIN CONCENTRATE" "MONIN FRUIT PURÉES/FRUIT MIX" "MONIN SAUCES" "MONIN LIQUEURS"]</td>
    <td>[text* product3]</td>
  </tr>
       <tr>
    <td>4</td>
         <td>[text text-550]</td> 
           <td>[select* brand-04 id:product4 "please select IBA associate member" "JIM BEAM FAMILY" "COGNAC" "PREMIUM BOURBON" "LIQUEUR" "JAPANESE WHISKY" "SCOTCH WHISKY"  "GIN" "DE KUYPER ESSENTIALS"  "DE KUYPER VARIATIONS"  "DE KUYPER SOURS""DE KUYPER ORIGINAL ELIXIRS"  "SPECIALITIES"  "RUTTE" "PREMIUMS" "CREAMS & ADVOCAAT" "PUCKERS & SCHNAPPS" "FABBRI SYRUPS" "ZERO RANGE"  "SPECIALS" "PULPS" "GOURMET SAUCE" "GOLD RANGE" "PITTED CHERRIES IN LIQUEUR" "CHERRIES IN LIQUE UR"  "SOUR LINE" "AMARENA FABBRI" "MOLECULAR" "MONIN PREMIUM SYRUPS" "MONIN CONCENTRATE" "MONIN FRUIT PURÉES/FRUIT MIX" "MONIN SAUCES" "MONIN LIQUEURS"]</td>
    <td>[text* product4]</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>5</td>
         <td>[text text-551]</td>
           <td>[select* brand-05 id:product5 "please select IBA associate member" "JIM BEAM FAMILY" "COGNAC" "PREMIUM BOURBON" "LIQUEUR" "JAPANESE WHISKY" "SCOTCH WHISKY"  "GIN" "DE KUYPER ESSENTIALS"  "DE KUYPER VARIATIONS"  "DE KUYPER SOURS""DE KUYPER ORIGINAL ELIXIRS"  "SPECIALITIES"  "RUTTE" "PREMIUMS" "CREAMS & ADVOCAAT" "PUCKERS & SCHNAPPS" "FABBRI SYRUPS" "ZERO RANGE"  "SPECIALS" "PULPS" "GOURMET SAUCE" "GOLD RANGE" "PITTED CHERRIES IN LIQUEUR" "CHERRIES IN LIQUE UR"  "SOUR LINE" "AMARENA FABBRI" "MOLECULAR" "MONIN PREMIUM SYRUPS" "MONIN CONCENTRATE" "MONIN FRUIT PURÉES/FRUIT MIX" "MONIN SAUCES" "MONIN LIQUEURS"]</td>
    <td>[text* product5]</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
         <td>[text text-552]</td>
           <td>[select* brand-06 id:product6 "please select IBA associate member" "JIM BEAM FAMILY" "COGNAC" "PREMIUM BOURBON" "LIQUEUR" "JAPANESE WHISKY" "SCOTCH WHISKY"  "GIN" "DE KUYPER ESSENTIALS"  "DE KUYPER VARIATIONS"  "DE KUYPER SOURS""DE KUYPER ORIGINAL ELIXIRS"  "SPECIALITIES"  "RUTTE" "PREMIUMS" "CREAMS & ADVOCAAT" "PUCKERS & SCHNAPPS" "FABBRI SYRUPS" "ZERO RANGE"  "SPECIALS" "PULPS" "GOURMET SAUCE" "GOLD RANGE" "PITTED CHERRIES IN LIQUEUR" "CHERRIES IN LIQUE UR"  "SOUR LINE" "AMARENA FABBRI" "MOLECULAR" "MONIN PREMIUM SYRUPS" "MONIN CONCENTRATE" "MONIN FRUIT PURÉES/FRUIT MIX" "MONIN SAUCES" "MONIN LIQUEURS"]</td>
    <td>[text* product6]</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
var brands = [["Jim Beam White","Jim Beam Black","Jim Beam Rye"],["Courvoisier VSOP","Courvoisier XO"],["Maker’s Mark"],["Midori"],["Hibiki Japanese Harmony"],["Auchentoshan American Oak","Auchentoshan 12Years Old","Auchentoshan Three Wood","Laphroaig 10 Years old","Bowmore Aged 12 Years"],["Sipsmith London Dry Gin","ROKU","Sipsmith V.J.O.P."],["De Kuyper Amaretto","De Kuyper Apricot Brandy","De Kuyper Blue Curaçao","De Kuyper Curaçao Triple Sec","De Kuyper Crème de Cacao Brown","De Kuyper Crème de Cacao White","De Kuyper Crème de Café","De Kuyper Crème de Cassis","De Kuyper Crème de Menthe Green","De Kuyper Crème de Menthe White","De Kuyper Marasquin","De Kuyper Parfait Amour","De Kuyper Triple Sec"],["De Kuyper Banana","De Kuyper Blackberry","De Kuyper Blueberry","De Kuyper Butterscotch","De Kuyper Cherry","De Kuyper Coconut","De Kuyper Dry Orange","De Kuyper Elderflower","De Kuyper Grapefruit","De Kuyper Mango","De Kuyper Melon","De Kuyper Passionfruit","De Kuyper Peach","De Kuyper Pineapple","De Kuyper Pisang","De Kuyper Raspberry","De Kuyper Watermelon","De Kuyper Wild Strawberry"],["DE KUYPER SOURS","De Kuyper Sour Apple","De Kuyper Sour Rhubarb"],["De Kuyper Classic Bitters","De Kuyper Cocoa Bitters","De Kuyper Juniper Bitters","De Kuyper Orange Bitters"],["Peachtree","Kwai Feh","De Kuyper Apricot Brandy","De Kuyper Cherry Brandy"],["Rutte Celery Gin","Rutte Dry Gin","Rutte Sloe Gin","Rutte Old Simon Genever"],["Mandarine Napoléon","Mandarine Napoléon XO","Bébo Cuban Coffee Liqueur","Heering Cherry Liqueur"],["ChocoVine","De Kuyper Piña Colada","De Kuyper Advocaat","Warninks Advocaat"],["De Kuyper Raspberry Pucker","De Kuyper Sour Apple Pucker","De Kuyper Apple Schnapps","De Kuyper Peach Schnapps","De Kuyper Butterscotch Schnapps"],["Almond Milk","Alpine Mint","Amarena","Amaretto","Anise","Banana","Bergamotto","Bitter","Caramel","Cedrata","Chai","Chocolate","Cinnamon","Coconut","Cola","Cranberry","Elderflower","Elderflowerberry","Falernum","Ginger","Gingerbread","Green Apple","Grenadine","Hazelnut","Irish Cream","Kiwi","Lemon","Lime","Litchi","Mandarin","Mango","Maracuja","Melon","Mint","Mojito","Orange","Orgeat","Papaya","Peach","Pineapple","Pomegranate","Raspberry","Rose","Strawberry","Strawberry Plus (Fragolapiù)","Sweet Almond Milk","Tamarind","Triple Sec","Tropical Blue","Vanilla","Violet","Watermelon","White Glacial Mint","Wild Forest Strawberry","Wild Fruits"],["Caramel Zero","Hazelnut Zero","Mint Zero","Vanilla Zero"],["Gum Nero","Agave Bio","Brown Sugar","Marendry bitter"],["Banana","Cranberry","Coconut","Green Apple","Grenadine","Kiwi","Mango","Melon","Papaya","Passion Fruit","Pomegranate","Raspberry","Strawberry","White Peach"],["Amarena","Amaretto","Blueberry","Caramel","Chocolate","ChocoWhite","Cocoa","Coconut","Coffee","Cotton Candy","Dulce De Leche","Elderberry","Green Apple","Hazelnut","Hazelnut & Chocolate","Kiwi","Limoncello","Liquorice","Mango","Mint","Orange","Passion Fruit","Raspberry","Salted Butter Caramel","Strawberry","Tropical Blue","Wild Fruits","Wild Strawberry","Yellow Peach","Yellow Vanilla","Zabaione"],["Amarena With Pieces","Caramelized Figs With Pieces","Cocoa And Hazelnut With Wafer","Dark Chocolate","Hazelnut","Maple","Pistachio","White Chocolate"],["Glass jar (470g)"],["Glass jar (470g)"],["Sweet & Sour powder","Sweet & Sour concentrate"],["Amarena Fabbri special for cocktail (1.25kg tin)"],["Spherication Bipack- 1 bottle MIX + 1 bottle FORM (900 g)","Aria & Velluto"],["Agave","Almond","Amaretto","Anise","Apple","Apple Pie","Apricot","Asian Lemongrass","Basil","Bitter","Black Forest","Blackberry","Blackcurrant","Blood Orange","Blue Curaçao","Blueberry","Brownie","Bubble Gum","Butterscotch","Candied Orange","Candy Strawberry","Caramel","Cheesecake","Cherry","Cherry Blossom","Cherry ( Morello )","Cherry Plum","Chestnut","Chocolate","Chocolate Mint","Cinnamon","Coconut","Coffee","Cotton Candy","Cranberry","Crème Brûlée","Cucumber","Curacao Triple Sec","Donut","Dry Tangerine Peel","Elderflower","Falernum","Flower Blossom","French Vanilla","Frosted Mint","Ginger","Gingerbread","Grapefruit","Green Apple","Green Banana","Green Mint","Grenadine","Guava","Gum","Hazelnut","Hibiscus","Honey","Irish Cream","Italian Dolce","Jasmine","Kiwi","Lavender","Lemon","Lemongrass","Lemon Ginger Honey","Lemon Pie","Lime","Lychee","Macadamia Nut","Macaroon","Mango","Maple Flavoured","Maple Spice","Matcha Green Tea","Melon","Mojito Mint","Orange","Orange Spritz","Osmanthus","Pandan","Passion Fruit","Peach","Peach White","Pear","Pina Colada","Pineapple","Pink Grapefruit","Pistachio","Pomegranate","Popcorn","Praline","Pumpkin Spice","Raspberry","Red Date","Roasted Chestnut","Roasted Hazelnut","Rose","Rum Flavour","Salted Caramel","Salted Pistachio","Sangria Mix","Speculoos","Spicy","Spicy Mango","Strawberry","Strawberry Wild","Tangerine","Tiramisu","Toffee Nut","Tonka Bean","Toasted Almond","Tropical Island Blend","Vanilla","Violet","Walnut Brownie","Watermelon","White Chocolate","White Grape","Wildberry","Winter Spice","Yellow Banana"],["Ceylon Tea","Chai Tea","Bitter","Cloudy Lemonade","Earl Grey Tea","Lemonade Mix","Lemon Tea","Lime Juice Cordial","Oolong Tea","Peach Tea","Rantcho Lemon","Rantcho Lime","Sweet and Sour"],["Banana","Beetroot","Blueberry","Carrot","Cherry","Coconut","Green Apple","Kiwi","Litchi","Mango","Passion Fruit","Pineapple","Peach","Raspberry","Red Berries","Rhubarb","Strawberry","Yuzu"],["Caramel","Chocolate Hazelnut","Dark Chocolate","Milk Chocolate","Salted Caramel","White Chocolate"],["Apricot Brandy 20%","Banana 20 %","Blackberry 16%","Blue Curacao 20%","Coffee 25%","Cassis de Dijon 16%","Cherry Brandy 24 %","Coconut 20%","Dark Cocoa 20%","White Mint 20%","Manzana verde 20%","Green Mint 20%","Green Melon 20%","Lychee 17%","Orange Curacao 24%","Peach 16%","Raspberry 18%","Strawberry 18%","Triple Sec Curacao 25%","Triple Sec Curacao 38%","Vanilla Madagascar 20%","Violet 16%","Watermelon 20%","White Cocoa 20%"]];
var brand, intIndex, brandId = '';
jQuery('select[name="brand-01"], select[name="brand-02"], select[name="brand-03"], select[name="brand-04"], select[name="brand-05"], select[name="brand-06"]').change(function(){
  intIndex = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').index();
  brand = brands[intIndex - 1];
  brandId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  jQuery('.' + brandId + ' select').remove();
  if( !!brand ){
    jQuery('.' + brandId + 'input').hide();
    jQuery('.' + brandId).append('<select name="' + brandId + '" id="select-' + brandId + '"><option value="">Please select a product</option></select>');
        jQuery.each(brand , function(i, item) {
            jQuery('#select-' + brandId + '').append($('<option>', { 
                value: item,
                text : item 
            }));
        });
    }else{
    jQuery('.' + brandId + ' input').show();
    }
    return false;
});
<!--End get products for per brand-->
```